# Cloudbees Jenkins shell access denied Facebook-iOS-SDK

Tags: ios, jenkins, cocoapods, cloudbees, facebook-sdk-3.0

Of course some shell commands are restricted from use on cloudbees. Is there any workaround for Facebook-iOS-SDK installation via cocoapods?

I just run

```
pod install
```

and in the installation of facebook sdk there's a script that is blocked by the system:

```
Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.16.2)
[!] /bin/bash 
set -e
find src -name \*.png | grep -v @ | grep -v -- - | sed -e 's|\(.*\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).png|scripts/image_to_code.py -i \1/\2.png -c \2 -o src|' | sh && find src -name \*.wav | grep -v @ | grep -v -- - | sed -e 's|\(.*\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).wav|scripts/audio_to_code.py -i \1/\2.wav -c \2 -o src|'  | sh

sh: line 12: src/FacebookSDKApplicationTests/ReferenceImages/FBLikeControlTests/testStyleStandard_1_123_2_2.png: Permission denied

sh: line 13: src/FacebookSDKApplicationTests/ReferenceImages/FBLikeControlTests/testStyleStandard_0_123_1_0.png: Permission denied

and so on..
```

This is just copying of resources so I wonder how can I manage to install it?

Answer (score 0):

The key error message is below, i believe you have same in bottom of error output.

```
sh: scripts/image_to_code.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The problem was caused by file formatter.

To quick solve this problem is enter this command :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python^M
```

refer:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2418